# Tkinter OptionMenu disabled but expandable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there any solution of write-protecting a `tkinter`  `OptionMenu` while retaining the possibility to inspect the available Options?

Background: I have a tkinter `OptionMenu` containing a selection of files that the user can "quick-load" into the application. However it might be that the user does not have permission to load new files.

I now indicate this by putting the `OptionMenu` in `disabled` state. But then the dropdown cannot be expanded anymore; meaning that the user cannot look at the available files.

Comment: Set a flag for user right and `if not user_has_no_right: quick_load`?

Comment: Since `OptionMenu` widgets don't support a callback function, your application must be doing something with respect to its current value. That means all you need is some flag to disable the selection of a file doing anything,,,except possibly indicating the operation can't be completed to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to disable the menu and still be able to open it just to see the list. The menu used in `OptionMenu` is tkinter `Menu()` and you can access it.

**Example:**

```
Op = OptionMenu(root, var, 'First', 'Second', 'Third')
Op.pack()

# Op_Menu is the Menu() class used for OptionMenu
Op_Menu = Op['menu']
```

Then you can do anything with the `Op` menu same as `Menu()`

---

### In your case , How to disable?

We can use `menu.entryconfig(index, options)` to configure `state = 'disabled' / 'normal'` as per the user.

**Example:**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('250x250+100+100')

str = tk.StringVar()
str.set('Select')

Op = tk.OptionMenu(root, str, "First", "Second", "Third")
Op.pack()


# This will disable the First and Third entries in the Op
# state = 'disable' / 'normal'
Op['menu'].entryconfig(0, state='disable')
Op['menu'].entryconfig("Third", state='disable')


entries = Op['menu'].index('end')     # This will get the total no. of entries.

# If you want to disable all of the entries uncomment below 2 lines.

# for i in range(entries+1):
#     Op['menu'].entryconfig(i, state='disable')


root.mainloop()
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dxmj.png]

For better understanding on how the `Menu()` is defined inside `OptionMenu` class can [check the source code of `OptionMenu()` class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ad4ed872415d00fcdfaa52a08108ec752b115000/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L3946). *(from line [3959](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ad4ed872415d00fcdfaa52a08108ec752b115000/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L3959))*

Answer (score 2):

You can disable each entry of the menu instead of disabling the optionmenu totally using `menu.entryconfigure(<index>, state='disabled')`. 
The menu of an optionmenu is stored in the 'menu' property:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar(root)
opmenu = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *['item %i' % i for i in range(5)])
opmenu.pack()
menu = opmenu['menu']
for i in range(menu.index('end') + 1):
    menu.entryconfigure(i, state='disabled')
```

So you can view all the items in the menu but they are not clickable.